# How git write-tree works internally?

Tags: git

I wonder how `git commit` works internally. On that, I mean, how the plumbing `git write-tree` works internally. I have the index with a couple of files, say:

```
% git ls-files --stage
100644 5376393fc691d519eb50baf65777249bf1fe1e15 0   dir1/file2
100644 e56e15bb7ddb6bd0b6d924b18fcee53d8713d7ea 0   file1
```

And I have two blobs inside my objects folder:

```
% ls -la .git/objects/
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  staff   96 May  5 16:47 53
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  staff   96 May  5 16:47 e5
```

As you can see, I need to create two trees in order to create a commit. So I write

```
git write-tree
```

and sure enough I got two more files inside my objects folder.

```
% ls -la .git/objects/
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  staff   96 May  5 16:52 22
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  staff   96 May  5 16:52 44
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  staff   96 May  5 16:47 53
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  staff   96 May  5 16:47 e5
```

My question is how to calculate this trees? What's the algorithm, that take only index file and create tree files?

Suppose my new index is this

```
100644 5376393fc691d519eb50baf65777249bf1fe1e15 0   dir1/file2
100644 5376393fc691d519eb50baf65777249bf1fe1e15 0   dir1/file5
100644 5376393fc691d519eb50baf65777249bf1fe1e15 0   dir1/dir2/file4
100644 5376393fc691d519eb50baf65777249bf1fe1e15 0   dir1/dir2/file3
100644 e56e15bb7ddb6bd0b6d924b18fcee53d8713d7ea 0   file1
```

I need to create a few trees from this index. I would start to make them from bottom to top. How do I know where is the bottom?

My guess is that we take everything before the first `/` and look for other blobs(or trees) with that prefix. Then we create a tree out of it.

Then we take everything before second `/` and repeat the process.

That looks performance bad to me.

What do you think?

Maybe you can show a piece of source code. (I was unable to find one)

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at *write_index_as_tree* in [cache-tree.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/74cc1aa55f30ed76424a0e7226ab519aa6265061/cache-tree.c), called from *cmd_write_tree* in [write-tree.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/142430338477d9d1bb25be66267225fb58498d92/builtin/write-tree.c).

Comment: Git carefully maintains its index such that `git write-tree` can consume it without a lot of work. If you're doing a more general "compute a Git tree from a directory full of files" problem, you must read the files and directories recursively, then sort the list into Git's pre-computed index sort order (which is *not* what you might expect!), and then write that out. You can find code that implements this [here](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/githash.py).

Comment: @torek As I understand, some special sorting is enough to ensure that I can create a tree from index and it would be valid? Then I can traverse the tree and write trees into the objects folder.

Comment: Read the code I show in my own Python program to see what is required for the sorting. The write-tree code in Git uses the index's properties to *cache* generated trees for later re-use (to make things go faster for some common cases), which complicates things. Were it not for these caches (which then require cache invalidation code as well) and a number of other special cases, the write-tree code in Git would be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add an answer (besides my comments) that addresses this particular point:

> I need to create a few trees from [an] index [that I created].

Git's so-called *plumbing commands*—including `git write-tree` and `git commit-tree`—let you build tree and commit objects piecemeal, for special purposes, by writing shell scripts.  This is a lot easier, albeit less efficient, than writing compiled code like a C or Java or Go program (in Java you can use JGit, and in Go there's a Go package, all of which have a lot of this written for you, but we'll just address use of C Git through the shell here).

The `git reset`, `git add`, and `git write-tree` commands, all of which can be used *as* plumbing (though `git reset` and `git add` aren't specifically meant as such) all accept and use an environment variable named `GIT_INDEX_FILE`.  This variable can be set to the path name of an existing file that contains a valid index, or a non-existent file that should be created holding a valid index.  Hence, in a shell script, you can do this:

```sh
set -e
tf=$(mktemp)
rm -f "$tf "                           # an empty file is invalid
trap "rm -f \"$tf\"" 0 1 2 3 15        # clean up on exit
GIT_INDEX_FILE="$tf" git reset         # build an index based on HEAD
GIT_INDEX_FILE="$tf" git add file1.ext
tree=$(git write-tree)
```

When (or rather if) this shell fragment finishes without failing, you've written out a Git tree object containing the current (`HEAD`) commit *plus* one file `file1.ext`.  (If the current commit contains a `file1.ext`, that file has been replaced with the one from the current working directory.)

You can use `git hash-object -w` and `git update-index` rather than `git add`; the `git update-index` plumbing command also obeys the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable.

Should you desire to create a specific tree *from scratch*, you can use `git mktree`, a plumbing command that reads `git ls-tree` format input files, and writes a tree object.

You can set `GIT_INDEX_FILE` and export it:

```sh
export GIT_INDEX_FILE="$tf"
```

which keeps it set in the environment for all future commands, if that's more convenient (but then you must `unset GIT_INDEX_FILE` to *undo* that if you want Git to use the normal index file).  In the above, I set it for each command that uses the index just to show which commands normally use "the" index (which is replaced with our chosen temporary file instead).  (All C Git commands obey this `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` setting if and when they use an index, unless they're doing their own special override-*the*-index-with-a-temporary internally.)

Note that all operations done with a temporary index and/or with `git hash-object -w` and with a tree object that has not yet been committed or tagged or otherwise made reachable must be completed before `git gc` might eat any of the created objects.  As `git prune` has a default grace period of 7 days and `git gc` has one of 14 days, and `git gc` is the usual eater of dead objects, you normally have 14 days to complete your task, which is usually sufficient in these days of multi-gigahertz CPUs.

Comment: That is some deep explanation of the entire process, I guess. Not sure if I understand what you are trying to say here. What I was asking is how git computes tree files out of index. Do I only need index file to create tree files? Or I also need to look inside working directory? From the python code you gave, it seems that I also need to look inside working directory.

Comment: A tree contains <name, mode, blob-hash> tuples, so that's what you need to create a tree. However, to create a tree that matches what *Git* would create, you must do it in the right order. You can do this yourself (as I did in that Python code), or you can *let Git do it* and that way it works regardless of what "the right order" is. "Let Git do it" is what I am suggesting here.

Comment: There are two ways to let Git do it for you: (1) use `git write-tree`, which generally means you must build an actual index, or (2) use `git mktree`, which means you must build the output that `git ls-files` would produce.

Comment: *If* you're going to do it manually: where will you get the <name, mode, hash-ID> tuples?

Comment: Yes, I do have the correct index with me, which was built when I was entering "git add file1" commands.

Comment: OK, then `git write-tree` does all the work for you. The only reason to investigate how `git write-tree` does that would be curiosity (which is fine), but to make progress with whatever your real goal is, just use `git write-tree`.

Comment: yep, I need to create write-tree command. That's why I'm asking all this. This is my homework - to write java git, in order to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

A `tree` is a recursive structure: It can contain files and other `tree`s. So to  create "the tree" you will need some recursion:

- find all directories that only contain files and subdirectories you already have a tree for (in the first iteration this will only find directories without any subdirectories)
- make a tree out of each of those directories
- repeat until there are no more unprocessed directories left

The last tree you created is for the root directory and that is the tree you put into your commit.

There is a good explanation in the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

For optimization I would

- make the algorithm iterative
- sort all index-elements by their nesting-depth (descending) and paths

That way you can just go through the sorted list and create the trees as you go. There will never be the situation that you need to reference a tree you did not yet create.

> That performance looks bad to me.

Since sorting is `O(n log n)` the whole algorithm is of that complexity. Quite OK I think.

Edit:

As @torek mentioned, the index is already sorted so the complexity is really just `O(n)`.

Comment: A Git index is maintained in sorted order, so that `git write-tree` does not have to sort it. Of course maintaining the list *in* sorted order is O(n log n) in the first place...